# "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]'" and "Cannot assign value of type 'ArraySlice' to type '[String]?'" errors in Swift

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift2

Xcode is giving me an error that makes no sense:

```
let command = ["", "", ""]
let task = NSTask()
task.arguments = command[1...command.count-1]
```

> Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]'

Why?

If I break it down:

```
let command = ["", "", ""]
let a = command[1...command.count-1]
let task = NSTask()
task.arguments = a
```

> Error: Cannot assign value of type 'ArraySlice' to type '[String]?'

Why is Xcode physically incapable of producing error messages that make sense? Surely the original code wasn't so massively complex as to confuse the compiler!

Also, why can't I assign an ArraySlice to a variable of type Array?

Answer (score 3):

It's because

```
let a = command[1...command.count-1]
task.arguments = a
```

you get arrayslice in "a" ArraySlice but task.arguments take `[String]?`

Now, you need to cast/convert arrayslice to array of string.
Use:

```
let a: [String] = Array(command[1...command.count-1])
```

Here, we took arrayslice and converted it in to array of type `[String]`.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArraySlice` just points to (parts of) an existing `Array` in memory. The "subarray" has not yet been copy-assigned to another memory position as the slice just describe a subset of an array that already exists in memory. However, to use it as an `Array` for `NSTask.arguments` setter, you need to coerce you `ArraySlice` to an `Array` (which coerces copy-assignment of your "subarray" followed by sending it to the setter of property `.arguments`).

```
let command = ["", "", ""]
let task = NSTask()
task.arguments = Array(command[1...command.count-1])
```

Also, I agree that XCode is not always on point when reporting errors. You did proceed with the correct approach here; breaking down your error-reported expression, where after the actual error message were given to you. I actually recognize the masking error *"Cannot subscript a value of type '[T]'"* as something I've stumbled upon myself when in fact the subsequent assignment of function call is the true root of the error.

Answer (score 0):

When unsure of an expression type (especially when the compiler complains), one thing you can do is use the dynamicType property to figure out what type is actually being generated.

```
print("\(command[1...command.count-1].dynamicType)")
// gives ArraySlice<String>.Type

print("\(command.dynamicType)"
// gives Array<String>.Type
```